# Lua eMail syntax Error

Tags: email, lua

I can not run following "mail" function in my code block:

mail(technicalte@gmail.com, testSubject, testMailBody)

I am getting the following error: 
   **Lua syntax error at line 4: ')' expected near '@'**

what does it mean, can you help me?

by the way the you can see the mail function below:

```
 function mail(to, subject, message)
  -- make sure these settings are correct
 local settings = {
 -- "from" field, only e-mail must be specified here
 from = 'technicalte@gmail.com',
 -- smtp username
 user = 'technicalte@gmail.com',
 -- smtp password
 password = 'mypassword',
 -- smtp server
 server = 'smtp.gmail.com',
 -- smtp server port
 port = 465,
 -- enable ssl, required for gmail smtp
 secure = 'sslv23',
 }

local smtp = require('socket.smtp')
local escape = function(v)
 return '<' .. tostring(v) .. '>'
end

 -- message headers and body
 settings.source = smtp.message({
 headers = {
  to = escape(to),
  subject = subject,
 },
 body = message
 })

-- fixup from field
settings.from = escape(settings.from)
settings.rcpt = { escape(to) }

return smtp.send(settings)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mail(technicalte@gmail.com, testSubject, testMailBody)
```

Should be

```
mail("technicalte@gmail.com",testSubject,testMailBody)
```

`technicalte@gmail.com` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: thank you, I made the following 

mail("technicalte@gmail.com", "test", "test")   and ı do not take an error but it does not send any mail,  is there an idea for the reason ?

Comment: and this is line #4 ?

Comment: no, I am calling the function after the function body in the code

Comment: maybe I found the reason, my internet connection has problems, tomarrow  I will try again thank you for your help